# error processing package bbb-client

Tags: ubuntu, bigbluebutton

i have followed documentation of http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html

between point 6 all has been installed correct and without errors
after 
**`$ sudo apt-get install bbb-check`**

have errors like bbb-client/bbb-check/bbb-config and more packages not found

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESY8M.jpg

```
    Reading state information... Done
bbb-check is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up bbb-check (1.0.0-1ubuntu37) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bbb-check.postinst: line 10: sudo: command not found
reload: Unknown instance:
dpkg: error processing package bbb-check (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up bbb-client (1.0.0-1ubuntu432) ...
reload: Unknown instance:
dpkg: error processing package bbb-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bbb-config:
 bbb-config depends on bbb-client; however:
  Package bbb-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bbb-config (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up bbb-demo (1.0.0-1ubuntu19) ...
reload: Unknown instance:
dpkg: error processing package bbb-demo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bigbluebutton:
 bigbluebutton depends on bbb-config; however:
  Package bbb-config is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bigbluebutton (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bbb-check
 bbb-client
 bbb-config
 bbb-demo
 bigbluebutton
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please put the errors you are getting as text and not an image.